# Are there consequences to running a 'long day' game?

Tags: dont-starve

I just started a 'long day' game by customizing the default world. Basically this means that I spend almost the entire game in daytime. I have a very small window of dusk and night that only last about 10 seconds each. I thought that having more time to explore and stock pile items would be helpful for eventually making it through winter (which I haven't been able to do yet). The pros for doing this seemed really obvious to me. But then I started wondering if there were any consequences to running a game that has a long day (or even a 'no night' game).

Are there certain things that happen at night that won't happen during the day that I'm missing out on? Is there anything that could eventually effect my survival?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Stuff you'll want at night:

- Sleeping mobs (Beefalo for hair, tallbirds for eggs, dangerous mobs for passing by safely), but you can put them asleep with darts or flutes, or just kill the mobs for the loot / safe passage.
- Finding fireflies (to relocate them, or make/refuel the miner hat)
- Losing sanity (but there are plenty of other ways to do that)

Usually, the shorter the night the better/easier, except for the fireflies.

Comment: Extra: since RoG, night is cooler than day, so a longer night has an additiional benefits of more hours without overheating.

Answer (score 2):

There are things that can only be done at night.  For instance, beefalos only sleep at night and while they are sleeping, you can take their hair for crafting hats and other items.

Answer (score 0):

For the moonstone event, you'd want a long enough night on a full moon to charge up your star caller staff to change it into moon caller staff.
Made this mistake, now using excel to calculate my "very short winter" + "long day" sandbox tweaks to see if i can get a long enough full moon night
::facepalm::